# "As the" vs "being the"

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

What is the difference between the two? Example:

> **As the** oldest member of the club, he should be the most responsible
>   one.
>
> **Being the** oldest member of the club, he should be the most responsible
>   one.

Do they mean the same? Or there's a subtle difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them mean "*because* he is the oldest member", so no semantic difference here.